# Why does $N(x+y)=N(y)=N(x)+N(y)$ imply that $N(x)>0$ and $N(y)>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have a lemma that I don't understand some part of in my textbook:

Lemma: Suppose $N:X\to [0,\infty)$ satisfies (i) and (ii) of the defintion of a norm and in addition that the set $B:=\{x:N(x)\leq 1\}$ is convex. Then $N$ satisfies the triangle inequality (1) $$N(x+y)\leq N(x)+N(y)$$ and so defines a norm on $X$.

Proof:

We only need to prove (1). If $N(x)=0$ then $x=0$ and $$N(x+y)=N(y)=N(x)+N(y)$$,

so we can assume that $N(x)>0$ and $N(y)>0$

Then the proof continues... Here, I don't understand one particular thing:

> Why does $N(x+y)=N(y)=N(x)+N(y)$ imply that $N(x)>0$ and $N(y)>0$?

Comment: It doesn't, it shows that the triangle inequality holds (with equality in fact) in that case, so you only need to consider the case when $N(x)>0$.  Since you can repeat the same argument for $N(y)=0$ you also only need to consider $N(y)>0$

Comment: Okay, I see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is saying that if we prove (1) when $N(x) >0$ and $N(y) >0$ that is good enough. This because in the remaining cases $N(x)=0$ or $N(y)=0$ and then (1) folows in  by the argument given.